# A question in Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite Abelian group, and $U$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$ with the maximal order.  Choose $y$ in $G-U$ such that $|y|$, the order of y, is the minimal. Suppose $p$ is a prime number and divides $|y|$, then prove that $<y^p>\le U$.
This is one step in proving $U$ has a compliment in $G$, and I just don't get this step. Why $y$ is not an element in $U$ but a subgroup $<y^p>$ is in $U$. I mean if $y$ is not in $U$, then $<y>$ wouldn't be $U$ is this correct? If so, how come a subgroup of $<y>$ is in $U$?

Comment: take the integer $\mathbb{Z}$, and the subgroup $9\mathbb{Z}$. $3$ doesn't belong to it, but $3^k$ does for all $k>1$

Comment: Presumably $U$ is meant to be a proper subgroup. Consider a simple example (often a good way to test run a proof). $G=\Bbb{Z}_4$, $U=\langle \overline{2}\rangle$, $y=\overline{1}$. Which powers (here multiples, because the group is additive) of $y$ are in $U$?

Comment: A finite abelian group is a product of cyclic groups. Consider where $y$ can lie.

Comment: You should say "a" subgroup of maximal order, not "the" subgroup. A unique one may not exist.

Comment: Thank you all, be very helpful.

Comment: @rogerl: This is presumably an initial step in the proof of the structure theorem of finite Abelian groups (a maximal cyclic group will be one summand, but one needs a complementary subgroup to see that it is actually a summand). Therefore using the structure theorem here would be misplaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually very easy.

$<y>$ isn't in $U$, but it doesn't mean that they are disjoint.
For example, in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{4Z}$, take $U=\{0,2\}$, and $y=1$.
you have that $y\not\in U$, but $<y>=\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{4Z}$, so it's not disjoint from $U$.
Moreover, $<2y>=U$

Comment: Thank you, I know how to prove that $y^p$ is in $U$

Comment: Here $U$ is not a maximal cyclic subgroup of $G$, since $G$ itself is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

The comment suggests that you may already have an answer, but here it is for the record.

The element $y^p$ has smaller order than $y$ (namely the order of $y$ divided by$~p$). Therefore by the choice of $y$, one cannot have $y^p\in G-U$, so $y^p\in U$. But since $U$ is a subgroup this imples $\langle y^p\rangle\subseteq U$.